# Immutable.Js - Add new property in Map

Tags: javascript, json, immutable.js

So let's say that I make a REST API call and receive a JSON in this format:

```
{
    "plan": {
        "createdDate": "05/04/2017",
        "location": {
          "city": null
          "state": null
        }
        "family": null
    }
}
```

And within in my reducer, make the JSON as an immutable as so:

```
Immutable.Map(Immutable.fromJS(action.json))
```

Along the way, is it possible to add properties under `family`?

For instance, when I am submitting a form to a server, ideally I like to send something like this:

```
{
    "plan": {
        "createdDate": "05/04/2017",
        "location": {
          "city": null
          "state": null
        }
        "family": {
          "father": "Homer",
          "mother": "Marge",
          "son": "Bartholomew"
        }
    }
}
```

Or do I have to initialized first to have those properties under `family` from the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this way via `mergeDeep` of [Immutable](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/mergeDeep):

```
const { fromJS } = require('immutable@4.0.0-rc.9')

const initialState = fromJS({
    "plan": {
        "createdDate": "05/04/2017",
        "location": {
          "city": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "family": null
    }
})

const newState = initialState.mergeDeep({
    "plan": {
        "family": {
            "father": "Homer",
            "mother": "Marge",
            "son": "Bartholomew"
        }
    }
})

console.log(newState.toJS())
```

You will got this result

```
{
    "plan": {
        "createdDate": "05/04/2017",
        "location": {
          "city": null,
          "state": null
        },
        "family": {
            "father": "Homer",
            "mother": "Marge",
            "son": "Bartholomew"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you for solving this same issue with me, I was succeed!

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement @julien-deniau answer. In case you have already properties in your object, you can use **mergeIn**. For example:

```
{
"plan": {
    "createdDate": "05/04/2017",
    "location": {
      "city": null
      "state": null
    }
    "family": {
      "father": "Homer",
      "mother": "Marge",
      "son": "Bartholomew"
      ---> you need to add smthg here
    }
}
```

}

```
state.mergeIn([
    'plan',
    'family'], {grandfather:'Abraham Jedediah'});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record, you don't need to do

```
const m = Immutable.Map(Immutable.fromJS(action.json))
```

But

```
const m = Immutable.fromJS(action.json)
```

does the job

Then you can just do:

```
const n = m.setIn(['plan', 'family'], /* your family object */)
```

Here :

```
const n = m.setIn(['plan', 'family'], Immutable.Map({ father: 'Homer', mother: 'Marge', son: 'Bartholomew' }))
```